# Loop over attribute values for executing SQL in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to know how may I accomplish the following use case in Nifi Flow:

I would like to execute SQL query for date range over a loop. The date range are provided from list of attribute values.

For example: If my list of attributes are : `2013-01-01 2013-02-01 2013-03-01`,  I would like to execute SQL operation over a loop such that:

```
 select * from where startdate>=2013-01-01 and enddate<2013-02-01
```

followed by:

```
 select * from where startdate>=2013-02-01 and enddate<2013-03-01
```

Therefore, for the same, I roughly know the idea but cant implement concretely:

`UpdateAttribute` (containing list of date values) -> `SplitText`-> `RouteOnAttribute` -> `ExecuteSQL`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In NiFi 1.8.0, you can use DuplicateFlowFile for this (via [NIFI-5454](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5454)). You can start with UpdateAttribute to add the count of delineated values in your list (let's assume it is an attribute called `datelist`), perhaps set `list.count` to

`${allDelineatedValues(${datelist}, " "):count()}`

Then in DuplicateFlowFile you can set Number of Copies to `${list.count:minus(1)}`. Each flow file downstream will have a `copy.index` attribute set (the original having index 0), so you can use that in ReplaceText in conjunction with `getDelimitedValue()`, perhaps setting the content to the following:

```
select * from myTable where 
  startdate >= ${datelist:getDelimitedField(${copy.index:plus(1)})} and 
  enddate < ${datelist:getDelimitedField(${copy.index:plus(2)})}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. However, I didnt get the idea behind DuplicateFlowFile properly. Can you possibly share with me the same scenario as a NIFI flow using just a test case datelist? That would be really helpful for me. Thank you